# Tomcat keeps giving me a false positive on a compilation error

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, gradle

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.4, Apache Tomcat 7.0.68, and JDK 1.8.0-74.

My Java project compiles successfully in IntelliJ. However, whenever I deploy my exploded WAR, I get this error from Tomcat:

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class com.myCompany.init.Log4jListener
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The import org.apache.log4j cannot be resolved
    ...(stack trace removed for brevity)
```

My class looks like this:

```
import java.util.PropertyResourceBundle;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator;
import org.apache.log4j.helpers.Loader;

import com.myCompany.AbstractEnvironment;

public class Log4jListener implements ServletContextListener {

    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "Alert";
    private static final String SYSTEM_KEY_EMAIL = "Alert";
    private static final String PROPERTY_FILE = "properties.environment";

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        // nothing to do
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        final PropertyResourceBundle bundle = (PropertyResourceBundle) ResourceBundle.getBundle(PROPERTY_FILE);

        final String emailInfo = AbstractEnvironment.getProperty(bundle, KEY_EMAIL);
        System.setProperty(SYSTEM_KEY_EMAIL, emailInfo);

        PropertyConfigurator.configure(Loader.getResource("properties/log4j.properties"));
        final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Log4jListener.class);
        logger.debug("Logger Initialized");
    }
}
```

The `org.apache.log4j` package comes from a Gradle dependency, which is included in my project:

[image: log4j dependency]

... and, in other classes in my project where I've instantiated a `Log4j` object from the same class, it doesn't complain about it.

What's even more interesting is that when a co-worker checked in my (the same exact) project on his computer, he didn't get this error, using the same version of IDEA, the JDK, and Tomcat.

IDEA doesn't tell me I have any Java errors. I did a Gradle `clean` and `build` task. I did a `Make Project` in IntelliJ. I rebuilt the artifacts in IntelliJ. I removed and re-added the artifact on the Tomcat Server, and I still get the same error.

This leads me to believe that this error isn't correct and may be a false positive, because the same exact project works on my co-worker's computer. Any ideas?

Comment: does your co-worker have the log4j.jar in the `tomcat/lib` folder?

Comment: @gapvision He does not. We don't use `log4j` for Tomcat's internal logging, just for our web application itself.

Comment: yes but jars from the `tomcat/lib` folder are included in the applications path. So its feasible to put some commonly shared libs there. Do you still have the error if you put the `log4j.jar` into this folder, just for fun.

Comment: @gapvision Yep, the error is still the same, unfortunately :(